# WordPress "wp_list_comments" custom order

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress 3.0.1 and want to order the comments from a post using a rating custom field.

Is this possible? I'm already using the callback property from wp_list_comments to customize the appearance of the comments.

Unfortunately this way I can only access the comments one by one and can't affect the order of the all result array.

I've already have a table with all the votes from the users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
// get comments of post 1234
$comments = get_comments( array('post_id' => 1234) );

// ... order your comments collection using php (eg. usort) here ...

// print your comments
wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$comments = get_comments('postId=x');`. It should be indexed by comment id. You can then look up the comment rating in your table.